# Joda-time How to get current standard time, not system time

Tags: jodatime

Using joda-time, how to get current standard time, not system time.

Comment: What do you mean by "current standard time"? UTC? Or something like PST ?

Answer (score 3):

The question is slightly ambiguous, but to get the current time you can simply use:

```
new DateTime();
```

This will give you the DateTime in the default Chronology (calendaring system) and the system TimeZone. However, if you want to create a DateTime object that is represented in a different or "standard time" zone to you. You can use:

```
new DateTime(DateTimeZone.UTC);
```

Or you can use DateTimeZone to construct a different time zone that you are interested in. For a more detailed explanation see: [DateTimeZone API Document](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTimeZone.html)